# Alternative ways to browse the python api

Tags: python, documentation, standard-library

Is it just me, or the python standard library documentation is extremely difficult to browse through?

- http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/index.html
- http://docs.python.org/3.1/modindex.html

Java has its brilliant [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/), Ruby has its helpful [Ruby-Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/), only in python I cannot find a good way to navigate through the standard library documentation.

There's the [Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) project, which looks nice, but does anyone know if it is actually being used on the standard library, so we can all go through it? If not, what are the alternatives people are using to browse python documentation.

Comment: Python and many of the big libraries use Sphinx for documentation. From a usability standpoint the generated docs are pretty horrible (even though they use some good-looking CSS). One example for that are the extremely long pages, which makes browsing very hard.

Comment: Wow... Python may not be the most wonderful docs, but comparing it unfavourably to *javadoc*? The doc is pretty much my least favourite thing about Java: you typically get a small superficial tutorial and then after that there is only the javadoc: a useless maze of class and method technical details with no directions for finding how everything's arranged and what you're expected to use.

Comment: I find the javadocs a great tool to browse APIs. The quality of the documentation itself is not responsibility of the tool, but of the documentation author. So IMHO, yes, javadocs are much better than what the official python documentation site is using.

Comment: -1:  Javadocs brilliant?  Sorry, can't see how you can justify that.  Do you have any specific issues that you can add to the question?  Any evidence?  Any specific, concrete features of javadocs that are somehow missing from the Python docs?

Comment: From the library producer p.o.v., writing javadocs can be annoying mainly due to the verbosity of HTML. From the library consumer p.o.v., javadocs are very simple and intuitive, one can find information about any given class or method in a matter of seconds. 'Brilliant' is perhaps a too strong word, but yes, as an API user I find them excellent. Do you want evidence? What is this, a religious debate?  Just browse the on-line jdk javadocs and the on-line python module index and compare...

Comment: I'm not even sure how you can compare the quality of the documentation of Python's API(s) vs. Java's. They aren't even the same types of languages. Java is strongly and statically typed! Of course you're going to find "browsing" the Python docs a little strange at first. Why? Because Python isn't riddled with thousands of classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually use the built-in [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html), if you are on windows it should be called Module Docs if you are on linux use `pydoc -p 8000` and connect through browser.

Answer (score 3):

`pydoc` from the command line, `help()` from the interactive interpreter prompt.

Answer (score 3):

`pydoc -p 8080`

The python community is semi-hostile to automatically generated documentation, especially if it's Object-Orientated. Python isn't just object-orientated (it's a multi-paradigm language), so Python developers generally prefer human-written documentation. Sometimes the functions are important, sometimes the Class structure is important.

Comment: Yeah, I have tasted some of the hostility...

Answer (score 2):

you can go to [here](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/etc/) and download the chm version of Python 3.1. With that, searching through the docs should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use the [python sidebar](http://www.edgewall.org/python-sidebar/) from Edgewall a long time ago.

These days, I google for the python function (the standard docs almost always show up as the first link).If I want to browse the source of the module (useful sometimes), I use this little shell function I wrote.

```
epy () {
    cmd="import $1 as a ; print a.__file__.endswith('.pyc') and a.__file__[:-1] or a.__file__" 
    file=$(/usr/bin/env python -c $cmd) 
    echo $file
    emacsclient --no-wait $file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm going to get downvoted but I find nothing wrong with the Sphinx docs and I find them way way better than the java alternative.

Comment: I agree. Sphinx is a good tool and it generates good docs. At least for Python :)